# Автоматическое заполнение полей Android Email

Tags: android, password, login

Когда - то экспериментировал с типами ввода в EditText, делал окошко с аутентификацией и тд. Приложение само запоминало что я туда вводил и в следующий раз выскакивала подсказка, если её нажать, то заполнялись сразу несколько полей. Я думал, что эта фишка на уровне ОС, но сейчас, когда мне стала нужна эта фишка, она сама не проявляется.
Ничего не запоминает и не выскакивает.
Что это была за функция и как мне с ней работать? sharedPreferens и подобное не интересует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете указать в вашем `XML` атрибут `android:autofillHints="email"`

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints="email"/>
```

Более подробно про механизм автозаполнения можно прочесть в [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize).